# Passing variable from one Jquery function to another

Tags: jquery, ajax

What im trying to do here is getting the id of a table on click function and then when i click the delete button it would get that id and delete it.

```
$("table tr").click(function () {
var id;
  $(this).removeClass('table-hover');
$(this).css("background-color", "#4682B4");
id = $(this).find(".id").html();
alert("Are you sure you want to delete data with id = " + id);  //using just to check if its getting the id of the row


});


 $('.btnDelete').click(function () {


$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'EmployeeDelete',
    data: JSON.stringify({ id: id }),
    success: function (data) {
               }
});
});
```

what am i doing wrong here

Comment: you are storing id in tr of table?

Comment: im getting the id of the tr and saving it to a var id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a button on each row in the following, and it is a row you want to delete. To grab the ID of the row I.

Each row of the table have a unique ID. The Jquery function below use the "closest" method and grabs the ID. From there you can delete it.

Here is the code, not tested, but it should work :-)

```
var button = $('.MyButtonClass');    $(button).on( 'click', function () {
        var rowID = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");
        //Delete the row });
```

Comment: no i have a button on the top what i do is when i click a row it will get the id and highlight the row and then when i will click the delete button it will delete that row thats why i need to pass the id from one function to another

Comment: Then I would go for the solution from Zim84 with a global variable. :-) You could save it as a session.storage in the browser. When the user clicks the row, the id is saved in the session.storage.Clicking the button grasps the session storage and deletes the row. Check:https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 1):

Your variable id is only valid inside that function. Try either
 - using the variable in a scope accessible for both functions
 - use the html-data attributes in the tr tag

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("table tbody tr").click(function (event) {


$(this).removeClass('table-hover');
$(this).css("background-color","#4682B4");
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined")
{
    sessionStorage.empID = $('td.id', this).html();
}
else{
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sory, browser does not support  web storage";
    }

$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'getID',
    data: JSON.stringify({ empID: sessionStorage.empID }),
    success: function (data) {
    },
    failure: function (response)
    {
        $('#result').html(response);
    }
});
 });
```

it got fixed by using sessionstorage thanks everyone